# ec2.SubnetType deploying to 2AZs rather than 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm having issues trying to deploy 3 subnets to a VPC using AWS CDK. Subnets are only deployed to 2x AZs instead of the default 3x

**Goal:**
To deploy an AWS VPC with 3x Isolated subnets using AWS CDK

**Expect Results:**
Using the costruct prop `subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.ISOLATED` within the VPC construct to create 3x isolated AZs

**Actual Results:**
Subnets are only deployed to 2AZs

**Code:**

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import ec2 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-ec2');

export class CdkWorkshopStack extends cdk.Stack {

  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

   new ec2.Vpc(this, 'VPC', {
    cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
    maxAzs: 3,
    subnetConfiguration: [
       {
         cidrMask: 28,
         name: 'Private Subnet',
         subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.ISOLATED,
       }
    ]
 });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

*'In an environment-agnostic stack, any constructs that use availability zones will see two of them'*

So I would have to explicitly define the environment of my stacks.

Documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html

Example Code:

```
new TestStack(app, 'TestStack', {
env: {
    region: "eu-central-1",
    account: "XXXXXXXX"
    }
});
```